# What is the simplest way to use Google map on Android with Qt 5.6?

Tags: android, qt, google-maps, opengl-es

When I try to use QQuickWidget to show QML of Mapbox (my custom access_token & map_id): http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtlocation-places-map-places-map-qml.html

Then it works fine on Windows/Linux, but black screen on Android 7.0 - API 24, with current **Android SDK tools 25.2.2**.

With output:

```
W libQtGUI.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShader::compile(Vertex): ERROR: Valid GLSL but not GLSL ES
W libQtGUI.so: (null):0 ((null)): *** Problematic Vertex shader source code ***
W libQtGUI.so: (null):0 ((null)): #define lowp
W libQtGUI.so: #define mediump
W libQtGUI.so: #define highp
W libQtGUI.so: #line 1
W libQtGUI.so: attribute highp vec3 vertexCoord;attribute highp vec2 textureCoord;varying highp vec2 uv;uniform highp mat4 vertexTransform;uniform highp mat3 textureTransform;void main() {   uv = (textureTransform * vec3(textureCoord,1.0)).xy;   gl_Position = vertexTransform * vec4(vertexCoord,1.0);}
W libQtGUI.so: (null):0 ((null)): ***
W libQtGUI.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): ERROR: Valid GLSL but not GLSL ES
W libQtGUI.so: (null):0 ((null)): *** Problematic Fragment shader source code ***
W libQtGUI.so: (null):0 ((null)): #define lowp
W libQtGUI.so: #define mediump
W libQtGUI.so: #define highp
W libQtGUI.so: #line 1
W libQtGUI.so: varying highp vec2 uv;uniform sampler2D textureSampler;uniform bool swizzle;uniform highp float opacity;void main() {   highp vec4 tmpFragColor = texture2D(textureSampler,uv);   tmpFragColor.a *= opacity;   gl_FragColor = swizzle ? tmpFragColor.bgra : tmpFragColor;}
W libQtGUI.so: (null):0 ((null)): ***
W libQtGUI.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShader::link: "'"
W libQtGUI.so: (null):0 ((null)): Could not link shader program:
W libQtGUI.so:  "'"
W libQtGUI.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShader::link: "'"
E emuglGLESv2_enc: glDrawArrays: a vertex attribute array is enabled with no data bound
E emuglGLESv2_enc: glDrawArrays: a vertex attribute array is enabled with no data bound
```

If I downgrade to **Android SDK tools 25.1.7** from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.1.7-windows.zip then  QQuickWidget shows fine QML of Mapbox on Android only on MainWindow, but but does not show anything on any other QDialog.

What is the simplest way to use Google map on Android with Qt 5.6?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can find unofficial QtLocation geoservice provider plugins on github that provide google tiles.
These maps can't be officially offered due to Google TOS preventing others to do so in application frameworks.